# Counting similar list element in a list

Tags: python, list, collections

I have a list of lists

```
list = [[1,0],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0]]
```

Now I want to count the number of occurrences similar list elements in the above list. 
e;g; `[1,0]:2, [1,2]:1, [1,1]:1`

I did

```
import collections
print Counter(list)
```

It throws error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 352, in __init__
    self.update(iterable, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 434, in update
    self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Counter` is internally a dictionary. The keys of the dictionaries should be hashble. But lists are mutable and they are not hashable. That is you are not able to use `Counter` as it is.

One option is to convert the nested list elements to tuples

```
my_list = [[1,0],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0]]
from collections import Counter
print Counter(map(tuple, my_list))
# Counter({(1, 0): 2, (1, 2): 1, (1, 1): 1})
```

If the list is too big, then you can use a generator expression like this

```
print Counter(tuple(item) for item in my_list)
```

this will avoid creating a new list in memory, unlike `map`. And using tuples work because tuples are immutable and are hashable.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you should be able to use .count() as it does in this earlier question. [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Comment: I don't know what are the items in my list are. I will have to find unique items and then do count for each to find its distribution. I think collections approach is shorter and neater.